# Selector In Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, performselector

I have doubt in Swift 3.0

In Objective-C you can declare a property for `selector` like this

```
@property (nonatomic,assign)SEL ItemSelected;
```

But how to declare a selector in Swift 3.0 as property because I would like to use this property in other class and should give action in that class.

I am trying to use it like this (Declared in tableview cell):

```
var itemSelected = #selector(selctedItem(_ :))
```

Using it in viewcontroller table view cell

```
cell.itemSelected(target: self, action: HomeViewController.self.selctedItem(_ :))
```

it's giving error

> use of Undeclared item selectedItem

I am not sure how to use in tableview with selctor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare selector in Swift 3 like this.

```
var itemSelected: Selector?
```

**Or**

```
var itemSelected = #selector(tapGesture)
```

Later you can use above `itemSelected` selector with action like this.

**For eg:**

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: itemSelected)
```

And `tapGesture` is declared like

```
func tapGesture(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) { }
```

**Edit:** You have added `collectionView` inside your `TableViewCell`, so to get the selected IndexPath of `CollectionViewCell`, declare one protocol and use it with your tableViewCell.

```
protocol SelectedCellDelegate {
     func getIndexPathOfSelectedCell(tableIndexPath: IndexPath, collectionViewCell indexPath: IndexPath) 
}
```

Now create one instance of SelectedCellDelegate and instance of `IndexPath` within your CustomTableViewCell.

```
class CustomTableCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    //All outlet

    var delegate: SelectedCellDelegate?
    var tableCellIndexPath = IndexPath() 

    //CollectionViewDataSource method

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
         self.delegate?.getIndexPathOfSelectedCell(tableIndexPath: tableCellIndexPath, indexPath: indexPath)
    }

}
```

Now inside your ViewController where you have added TableView implement the protocol `SelectedCellDelegate` and set the `delegate` and `tableCellIndexPath` in `cellForRowAt indexPath` method.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, SelectedCellDelegate {
     //your methods

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
          let cell // Initialize the cell with your custom TableCell 
          cell.delegate = self
          cell.tableCellIndexPath = indexPath
          return cell
     }
```

Now add the delegate method in your ViewController.

```
func getIndexPathOfSelectedCell(tableIndexPath: IndexPath, collectionViewCell indexPath: IndexPath)  {
     print("TableView cell indexPath - \(tableIndexPath)")
     print("CollectionView cell indexPath - \(indexPath)") 
}
```

Comment: What if i dont like to put param ItemSelected  its giving error like unresolved identififer . if i declare  var selector = #selector() its giving error

Comment: @IOS_PROGRAMMER Declare it like first eg optional `var itemSelected: Selector?` and latter sets its value.

Comment: if i declare it as oprional it is telling cannot call non-functiontype

Comment: @IOS_PROGRAMMER Edit your question with new code that you are trying.

Comment: @IOS_PROGRAMMER you are not making sense here, you have declare it inside tableView cell and using it like `HomeViewController.self.selctedItem(_ :)` what do you want to achieve first clear that.

Comment: @IOS_PROGRAMMER Is it working now or not? You haven't reply?

Comment: cell.selItemSelected = #selector(HMHomeViewController.self.selctedItem(_:))
i wrote it like this error gone but  function not getting called  in cell i  delcared in like this     var selItemSelected : Selector!
i dont want to delcare this in view controller coz in awake from nib i wanted to call other cell so i did like this

Comment: @IOS_PROGRAMMER Change it like this `cell.selItemSelected = #selector(self.selctedItem(_:))` also where you have used selItemSelected show that also.

Comment: No where only in viewcontroller here cell.selItemSelected = #selector(self.selctedItem(_:))  and self.selectedItem fucn not getting called i just delcared it in tabeivewView cell and used here

Comment: @IOS_PROGRAMMER You have just initialized the selector you need to set its value on some button action or what ever place you want.

Comment: yes on click of collectionview  cell i want to perform action so i write it like this  cell.rowIndex = indexPath.section    i loaded a collectionview into tableview  so am trying to give action to cell through selector coz i have loaded mutiple collectionviews into tableview with sections

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131496/discussion-between-ios-programmer-and-nirav-d).